# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Advertisement' in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I have a class that name is Advertisement:

```
 public class Advertisement
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

and in my controller:

```
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    public UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    // Post api/Order/Test

    [Route("Test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test(Advertisement advertisement)
    {
        var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        Task<IdentityUser> user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(currentUser);

      return Ok(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    }
```

but when I test it with Postman I face this error,

```
 "Message": "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
"ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Advertisement' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",
"ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

Can AnyBody help me?

Comment: From the error i appears that you have no Content-Type header? Add the appropriate header Content-Type in your Postman call and that should fix it.

Comment: I have `Content-Type` and `Accept` in my headers @DaveAgaba

Answer (score 49):

In your `WebApiConfig.cs` add this inside of register

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
```

Comment: This does not work.    
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.CanWriteType(typeof(MyModel));   returns false.

Comment: Even though this answer is the best-working one for this problem, modifying a working WebAPI isn't what I expect to do to solve a problem. I'm sure Postman can be set up to send the correct data instead of modifying the server to receive unexpected data types just because you need to test and are unable to build a proper solution. In short, I want to test what I'm going to receive from the client, not a different approach.

Comment: Had a similar scenario to the OP when trying to post `multipart/form-data`.  I tried adding this line and swapping out `application/octet-stream` for `multipart/form-data`.  Should've worked, but it didn't - still got the same 500 error again as the OP, just mine references `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 4):

> "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Advertisement' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",

That means that your application cannot read octet-stream Content-Type - which is what the request provided. This is one frustration I have with Web API. However there is a way around it. The easy way is to modify the Content-type to 'application/json' or 'application/xml' which is easily read. 
The harder way is to provide your own MediaTypeFormatter.

Comment: The 'this' tutorial link is now dead.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

1. Instead of posting it as `application/octet-stream`, use `application/json;charset=UTF-8`, instead.
2. `public IHttpActionResult Test(Advertisement advertisement)` needs to have `[FromBody]` in it:

   `public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody]Advertisement advertisement) { ... }`

   By default, the ApiController expects anything being passed in to represent URL parameters, so you'd need that `[FromBody]` for any data you are posting in the Request Body that you want parsed out.
3. You need to decorate your Post method with `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]` so that it doesn't think it's the MVC version `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]`.  Ensure you put the full thing, because `[HttpPost]` will also default to the MVC version.  It's probably not a bad idea to rename `Test` to `Post`, as well, though you might be using that for a Unit Test method, so not sure on that one.
4. Send your data as JSON:  `{ Title: "some title", Desc: "some description" }`
5. Do something with `advertisement` inside your `Post()` function:

   `string title = advertisement.Title;
    string desc = advertisement.Desc;`

Comment: "By default, the ApiController expects anything being passed in to represent URL parameters"...I don't believe this is true, and it's not my experience of using it, either. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api where it says _"By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters: ....For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body"_

Comment: @ADyson Except there's nothing to tell it to read from the body if you don't specify that tag. If you don't let it know to expect there to be a "complex type", it doesn't know it is there. Trust me. Try running it without that `[FromBody]` tag and see how far you get before you just criticize. Despite what any documentation might say, there's no replacement for practical application of the knowledge. And believe it or not, even Microsoft gets things wrong, sometimes. There was an example of a multi-part POST that MS had on their site that didn't even work.

Comment: "If you don't let it know to expect there to be a "complex type" "...sorry but what do you mean? a complex type is any kind of object which isn't one of the simple types e.g. int, string etc. So if you put `Advertisement advertisement` (per the example in the question) as a parameter in the action method, then by definition the model binder will know about it, and since it's not one of the defined simple types, it must be a complex one. So  it'll try and read it from the body by default, unless you specify otherwise. I've got plenty of working examples (using Web API 2  / .NET 4.6).

Comment: The actual issue here appears to be (although we don't quite have enough info to be sure) that the client appears to be sending the wrong content-type header. I don't think there's much, if anything, wrong with the WebAPI side.

Comment: @ADyson While it's true the wrong content-type was applied-again-try it out if you don't believe me, but you won't get very far if you don't specify `[FromBody]`. It assumes that the values are coming from URL parameters-& not the POST (body)-if you do not include that.  He also did not include the `[HttpPost]` decoration, so it would not accept the POST to begin with, without that. Then there's the matter of how he didn't even use the `advertisement` object in his API function. I didn't include all of these faults for my health, but to make it so it would work & inform others on how to do so.

Comment: Like I said I've got plenty of examples where it works fine without doing that. I do it all the time. Maybe you write your code a different way somehow, or it's a different version (.NET Core maybe? I haven't used it yet), I don't know. All I know is I've never needed it to do it explicitly. Possibly the absence of the HttpPost attribute is an issue, although OP never stated what method they were using for the request - but if they're using GET then a content-type error wouldn't make much sense. BTW I agree that not actually using the input object is silly but it's not part of the stated issue

Comment: @ADyson You might have a point-did some more research: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api -it confirms what you said, the default behavior *is* supposed to grab a complex obj (such as `advertisement`) from the body by default & simple ones from the URL params, without needing tags. I had a JSON object I had stringified & was posting, trying to model bind it, & found without `[FromBody]`, it would be null. Pretty sure I was using .NET 4.5.2, but I looked up Core & it seems to require the tags: https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I was also using `application/json` as my Content-Type instead of the recommended `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so that likely played a part.  And yeah, I was assuming he was doing a POST.  As you said, his error wouldn't make any sense if it was a GET.  But even then, he would've needed an `[HttpGet]` tag, then. As for not using the input object & putting it in my answer, did that to be thorough.. I hate answers that solve a superficial problem, but then don't provide fixes for other ones to make it work the rest of the way. :)

Comment: If you are trying to pass an object argument to a GET method, you need to make sure that you have [FromUri] on the argument of the controller method. I had recently run into this issue when I switched from individual arguments to an object with those arguments as properties.

Comment: @DesertFoxAZ No, I have `[FromBody]` for that purpose, and ON PURPOSE. `[FromUri]` is for trying to pass values by URL parameter.