# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'StreamContent' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to call a method that returns a file in my asp.net web api from win app, but getting the following error:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'StreamContent'  from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'

I have checked every bit of my code, but i don't know how to fix the issue.

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49681/api/ZipFile/");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

// _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment"));
HttpResponseMessage resp = _client.GetAsync("DownloadFile?fileName=/" +  startPath).Result;
if (resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //var file = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
    var fileDownloaded = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<StreamContent>().Result;

     Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"c:\test\" + fileDownloaded);
    //ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file, extractPath);
    //MessageBox.Show(resp);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusCode.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Advertisement' in asp.net web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544009/no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-type-advertisement-in)

Comment: What kind of files are you downloading? `application/octet-stream` implies they can be anything. Perhaps you can use `HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync` and assign that to `fileStream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just magically convert the content of the HTTP response to `StreamContent` using `ReadAsAsync<StreamContent>` - you need to tell the system how to do so via a `MediaTypeFormatter` (that you would have to write as there is no `ReadAsStreamContentAsync`). However it would be much easier to just read the content as a byte array (or stream - using ReadAsStreamAsync) and then create the file on disk using that:

```
var fileDownloaded = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@"c:\test\" + yourFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    await fileStream.WriteAsync(fileDownloaded, 0, fileDownloaded.Length);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use this code, but "file.Length" is the issue. what variable is "file"?

Comment: You also need to ensure you are awaiting the async methods you call. Your code in the question does not do so (_client.GetAsync) so you will not get returned the final results of the calls you are making.

Comment: fileDownloaded.Length  - I'm getting Task<Stream> does not contain a definition for 'Length'.   When I commented this line await fileStream.WriteAsync(fileDownloaded, 0, fileDownloaded.Length); I got my file downloaded but reads 0 bytes

Comment: See my comments above re. awaiting async method calls. If you don't await the call you will be returned a `Task<byte[]>` rather than a `byte[]`.

Comment: I did according to your illustration. I'm having issue with this line: await fileStream.WriteAsync(fileDownloaded, 0, fileDownloaded.Length);

Comment: You would only be getting an error regarding `Task<Stream>` if you called `ReadAsStreamAsync`. Await `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` and then you shouldn't get any error with the call to  `fileStream.WriteAsync` (unless you can't access the file location or other issues not connected to the original question).

Comment: I really appreciate your time and efforts. After beating about the bush for almost a day, i realized that the problem was actually from my method header, I fixed that and this works for me. Again, thanks so much.